# Insert record to database show case number to user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

pretty new to this so go easy on me.

Basically I'm creating a form (in visual studio c#) were users submit a record to the database. Once the form has been submitted (I'm using a stored procedure to collect the information from text boxes and insert into tables) I would like an alert box to pop up and say something like ... The case has been successfully submitted the new record is (new case number) please keep note of the case number .....

Problem I'm having is how do I get the alert box with the case number ? The Case number is the primary key in the table and is set for auto increment.

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Allow me to explain, because you are new to the site. StackOverflow is commonly seen as a programmers forum. This is true. It is also commonly seen as a place to say "How do I do this?", which it is not. This is most likely the cause for your downvotes and your question's inevitable close.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Comment: @Key-eat, I would suggest you read the FAQ then: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ...specifically: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. ` ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you use SQL Server, it will be pretty easy. In your stored procedure, if you call `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after you insert a record, it gives you the Case Number of the row just inserted.

Now, you can either return this number from your stored procedure using `RETURN` command (yes! stored procedures can return an integer, but keep in mind that it is usually used for returning error numbers), or use an `OUTPUT` parameter for that matter. You'll find a simple example [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).